# Can not store IDs to Array because content of .each is ignored

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, each, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to get the IDs of the list-elements of my sortable connected lists (built with jQuery UI). Unfortunately the content of the .each() function is not running. I tried a lot. For testing I have an alert inside the function. It never appears. My lists are generated from wordpress posts. They all do have ID's.

Code from Wordpress Template:

```
<div id="content-start" class="container content content-start">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 main">
    <h2>Alle Artikel</h2>
    <p>Sie können die gewünschten Artikel per „Drag and Drop“ in dem Kasten auf der rechten Seite sammeln.</p>

    <?php
      $post_auswahl = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => array('insights'),
        'order_by' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC'
      ));
    ?>

    <?php
    if($post_auswahl->have_posts()) : ?>
        <ul id="liste-alles" class="liste-alles list-column sortable-list connectedSortable">
            <?php while($post_auswahl->have_posts()) : $post_auswahl->the_post(); ?>

                <li <?php post_class(); ?> id="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><div class="white-box sortable-items"><h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4></div></li>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>

</div>

<div class="col-md-4 side">
    <h4>Meine Auswahl</h4>

        <ul id="liste-auswahl" class="liste-auswahl list-column sortable-list connectedSortable">

        </ul>

</div>
```

The jQuery Code:

```
// Get all items from a container
function getItems()
{

    var columns = [];

    $("#content-start ul.column").each(function(){

        columns.push($(this).sortable('toArray').join(','));

        alert("Values added...");

    });

    return columns.join('|');

};


$( function() {
    $( "#liste-alles, #liste-auswahl" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        placeholder: "platzhalter-item",
        update: function(event, ui) {

        var itemStr = getItems();
        console.log({
          MyIDs: itemStr
        });


        },
        start: function(event, ui){        

            ui.item.addClass("dragging");
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){ 
            ui.item.removeClass("dragging");
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: You don't have any `ul.column` elements, they seem to have the class `list-column` ?

Comment: Oh maaaan... I changed that a while ago, but forgot to change the template too.... Now it works like a charm... Thank you so much!